# $_GET[''] not returning a value

Tags: php, get

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$aid = $_GET['aid'];
echo 'test';
echo $aid;
echo $cid;
```

http://whatever.com/script.php?cid=40?aid=20

$cid and $aid do not echo values. Echoing is not my intended usage, I'm trying to compare $aid to a value I get from the database using $cid.

When I noticed my comparison statement validating true when it was definitely supposed to be false, I echoed out the vars and realized the statement is returning true because they are both null.

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: `script.php?cid=40?aid=20` is wrong! it should be `script.php?cid=40&aid=20`

Answer (score 2):

Your test URL should not have two question marks. Use ampersands for additional parameters after the first.

```
http://whatever.com/script.php?cid=40&aid=20
                                     ^
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel very silly.